# How do I log responses from different conversations with a DialogFlow bot on different Firebase documents?

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es

I've been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8iaKOjyqnM&lc=Ugy2HB6n48TlAkoRqPZ4AaABAg.997ZSTnnEoV99I2ZfxcL0M), but it seems like every time we shoot in the same place. I wish I could record the responses separately for each Facebook client. Do you know how I can do that?

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion, Payload} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var answers = [];
var score = {};

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL:'ws://la-base-de-datos.firebaseio.com/'
});

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

function fallback(agent) {
  agent.add(`I didn't understand FULLFILMENT`);
  agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again? FULLFILMENT`);
}

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Salut! C'est Jacques. Et ouai, je suis revenu d'outre-tombe?`);
    agent.add(`J'étais maire de la ville autrefois tu sais?`);
    agent.add(`Si ca te dit je te pose quelques questions pour savoir quel candidat pourrait te correspondre?`);
    agent.add(`Et quels sont les gens qui partagent tes opinions autour de toi!`);
    agent.add(`On y va?`);
    agent.add(new Suggestion("C'est parti!"));
  }

  function answerIntroductionHandler(agent){
    agent.add('Super! Quel est votre arrondissement? (I, ..., XIII, ...)');
  }

  function answerArrondissementHandler(agent){
    const arrondissement = agent.parameters.text;
    admin.database().ref("data").set({
        arrondissement: arrondissement
    });
    agent.add(new Card({
        title: '1/11 Faut-il accélérer l’automatisation ',
        imageUrl: 'http://www.leparisien.fr/resizer/mz-PnB5RECZ1q-z9GDRvlB_3jsg=/932x582/arc-anglerfish-eu-central-1-prod-leparisien.s3.amazonaws.com/public/RJPSM346RO4M5VIDDOS35APBII.jpg',
        text: 'du métro ?'
      })
    );
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Oui"));
    agent.add(new Suggestion("Non"));}

  function answer1Handler(agent){

    const answer = agent.parameters.Boolean;

    if(answer === 'true'){
      score.griveaux = (score.griveaux+1) || 1 ;
    }else{
    }

    admin.database().ref("data").set({
        accelerer_metro: answer
    });

    answers.push(answer);

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('answerIntroduction', answerIntroductionHandler);
  intentMap.set('answerArrondissement', answerArrondissementHandler);
  intentMap.set('answer1', answer1Handler);


  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

And my database looks like this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database uses a simple JSON model for storing data, hence you can create separate objects inside `data` to store the values by using [push](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push)

Chaning this

```
admin.database().ref("data").set({
    accelerer_metro: answer
});
```

to

```
admin.database().ref("data").push({
    accelerer_metro: answer
});
```

By this you would be able to store all the logs, but they would be un-identifiable. A better approach could be having separate storage link for each user.

For identifiable information, you can use either user id (from `conv.user.access.token` or if you have stored an id in `storage`) or use the conversation id `conv.id`

```
admin.database().ref(`data/${conv.id}`).update({
    accelerer_metro: answer
});
```